# Horizontal scroll when check box is unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, event-handling, horizontal-scrolling

I'm a little stuck on something which I'm working on and hoping someone could help me out.

The page I'm making at the moment involves scrolling horizontally using this piece of code I found on CSS Tricks.

```
    $(function() {

       $("body.story").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

          this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

          event.preventDefault();

       });

    });
```

The website itself involves different layouts for different pages, hence the different body classes. The navigation I have created is using the checkbox hack technique of which the height will be more than 100% of the page. So if anyone is still following when the checkbox navigation is not being used and therefore unchecked i'd like to run the above code and allow the page to scroll horizontally but when the checkbox is checked and the tall menu is showing I'd like to disable the horizontal scroll and then revert back to regular vertical scrolling.

If anyone needs a demo to see what I'm trying to get at the project is located at http://projects.minml.co/baptistella2

The html for the checkbox is as follows

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<label for="toggle"></label>
```

I understand I need to use an event handler but I have no idea where to begin and would appreciate a helping hand.

Thanks

Comment: you are looking for `is(':checked')`.  `if($('#toggle').is(':checked')`

Comment: is that project yours or one you are trying to replicate?

Comment: This is my project> i'm just stuck on the scroll issue

Comment: So where is the checkbox and what page should scroll vertically?

Comment: Sorry my bad if you go to this page [link](http://projects.minml.co/baptistella2/content/story-one)
the checkbox controls the navigation in the top right. essentially its a div that covers the full screen and will scroll vertically. any time this div is not shown then the page needs to scroll horizontally. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Ahh okay. Just remove the preventDefault when the nav div is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the preventDefault when the navbar is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to toggle the "mode" of scrolling on the fly. In that case I would recommend storing a simple variable, say "scrollMode" and flip it based on the menu being opened and closed between "horizontal" and "vertical". Then your mousewheel event code checks that variable before doing any custom behavior.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure I completely follow.
From what I understand when the checkbox is checked you want to disable horizontal (y-axis) scrolling
and when it's not checked you want to allow horizontal scrolling. 
If that is the case I would just use jquery to change the css  overflow-y property

```
   if($('#toggle').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('body.story').css('overflow-y' , 'hidden');
    }else{
        ('body.story').css('overflow-y' , 'scroll');
    }
```

or

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
    ('body.story').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```

then in your css make a class no-scroll and set overflow-y:hidden

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for your suggestion, I'm looking to use the mouse wheel to scroll. simply changing the overflow on a div wouldnt allow it to scroll horizontal then vertical based upon the checkbox. on the link i posted if you click on one of the story links you will see the page scrolls horizontally then when the menu is clicked the page now scrolls vertically although not with the mouse wheel. I hope this is clearer